# Counting word occurrences from specific part of txt files using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder with a number of txt files. 
I want to count the number of occurrences of a set of words in a certain part of a each txt file and export the results to a new excel file.
Specifically, I want to look for the occurrences of words only in part of text that begins after the word "Company A" and ends in the word "Company B."

For example:

I want to look for the words "Corporation" and "Board" in the bold part of the following text:

...the Board of **Company A oversees the management of risks inherent in the operation of the Corporation businesses and the implementation of its strategic plan. The Board reviews the risks associated with the Corporation strategic plan at an annual strategic planning session and periodically throughout the year as part of its consideration of the strategic direction of Company B**. In addition, the Board addresses the primary risks associated with...

I have managed to count the occurrences of the set of words **but from the whole txt file** and not the part from Company A up to Company B.

```
import os
import sys
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('file path' + '**/*', recursive=True):
    def countWords(filename, list_words):
        try:
            reading = open(filename, "r+", encoding="utf-8")
            check = reading.readlines()
            reading.close()
            for each in list_words:
                lower = each.lower()
                count = 0
                for string in check:
                    word_check = string.split()
                    for word in word_check:
                        lowerword = word.lower()
                        line = lowerword.strip("!@#$%^&*()_+?><:.,-'\\ ")
                        if lower == line:
                            count += 1 
                print(lower, ":", count)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("This file doesn't exist.")
        for zero in list_words:
            if zero != "":
                print(zero, ":", "0")
            else:
                pass
    print('----')
    print(os.path.basename(filename))
    countWords(filename, ["Corporation", "Board"])
```

The final output for the example text should be like this:

- txtfile1
- Corporation: 2
- Board: 1

And the above process should be replicated for all txt files of the folder and exported as an excel file.

Thanks for the consideration and I apologize in advance for the length of the question.

Answer (score 0):

you might try regexp, assuming you want the whole string if you see repetitions of company a before you see company b.

```
re.findall('company a.*?company b', 'company a did some things in agreement with company b')
```

That will provide a list of all the text strings starting with company a and ending with company b.